# Load multiple models with PyFMI

Tags: python, memory, instantiation

I am attempting to instantiate several simulation slaves in a master algorithm using `pyfmi`.

For instance:

```
models = []
for path in fmuList:
    models.append(pyfmi.load_fmu(path))
```

The problem I get is that eventually an exception is raised:

```
***FMUException: Failed to instantiate slave.
```

Calling the same for loop in the `pdb` trace debugger I see that each model is successfully loaded, however, each is loaded to the same location in memory.  For example:

```
<pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS1 object at 1xxxxxxxxx>
<pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS1 object at 1xxxxxxxxx>
...
```

How should I properly instantiate multiple FMUs with pyfmi?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that pyfmi cannot change the working directory, and thus the different models use the same folder 'Output_EPExport_Slave' with the same socket and variables files. You have to manually change the working directory.

Use instead:

```
from   os                            import chdir
from   pyfmi                         import load_fmu
fmus        = {}
for id in id_list:
    chdir(fmu_path+str(id))
    fmus[id]  = load_fmu('f_' + str(id)+'.fmu',fmu_path+str(id))
    fmus[id].initialize(start_time,final_time)
```

In this way, it is also easier to call the models.